# Wifi keeps disconnecting on Lenovo G480

Tags: wireless

I'm using Lenovo G480 and I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS yesterday (dual booting it with Windows 7).  My wifi connection keeps on connecting and disconnecting every 5 to 10mins. I'm a newbie to Linux and I have no idea how to fix this. Can someone help?

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1058 (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8162 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)
```

sudo lshw -C network

```
*-network               
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
   resources: irq:17 memory:eb500000-eb503fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: AR8162 Fast Ethernet
   vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 10
   serial: 3c:97:0e:19:f2:bf
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx driverversion=1.2.3 firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:19 memory:eb400000-eb43ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 3
   logical name: wlan0
   serial: 08:ed:b9:a5:9b:a1
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=3.5.0-34-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.254.101 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

lsmod:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_utf8               12558  1 
isofs                  40307  1 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32476  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    79855  1 
joydev                 17694  0 
rfcomm                 47562  0 
bnep                   18240  2 
parport_pc             32867  0 
ppdev                  17114  0 
lp                     17800  0 
parport                46563  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
coretemp               13642  0 
kvm                   422160  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13221  0 
arc4                   12530  2 
aesni_intel            51134  2 
cryptd                 20531  2 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
aes_x86_64             17256  1 aesni_intel
brcmsmac              541775  0 
mac80211              555272  1 brcmsmac
brcmutil               14756  1 brcmsmac
cfg80211              208382  2 brcmsmac,mac80211
cordic                 12575  1 brcmsmac
snd_hda_intel          34063  3 
snd_hda_codec         135141  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              17765  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                97523  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13325  0 
snd_rawmidi            30750  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14900  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61931  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              29990  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14498  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
btusb                  22432  0 
bluetooth             211812  14 rfcomm,bnep,btusb
alx                    73500  0 
uvcvideo               78117  0 
mdio                   13808  1 alx
videobuf2_core         33025  1 uvcvideo
videodev              125126  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
videobuf2_vmalloc      12861  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13405  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
microcode              23030  0 
snd                    83674  16 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
psmouse               102506  0 
serio_raw              13216  0 
lpc_ich                17145  0 
bcma                   35762  1 brcmsmac
mei                    41410  0 
ideapad_laptop         18235  0 
soundcore              15092  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18573  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
sparse_keymap          13891  1 ideapad_laptop
nouveau               924024  1 
ttm                    88495  1 nouveau
mxm_wmi                13022  1 nouveau
mac_hid                13254  0 
wmi                    19257  2 nouveau,mxm_wmi
i915                  535221  3 
drm_kms_helper         49259  2 nouveau,i915
drm                   290059  7 nouveau,ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13565  2 nouveau,i915
video                  19653  2 nouveau,i915
usb_storage            49288  0 
ahci                   25869  2 
libahci                27338  1 ahci
```

Thanks. Your help would be greatly appreciated. God bless :)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the `linux-firmware-nonfree` package:

`sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`

Comment: Are there any other way I can download it via windows? I can't connect to my wifi right now. thanks.

Comment: Yes, just select a mirror here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/all/linux-firmware-nonfree/download